# Does SQL Server Compact (CE) support a RequiresNew transaction scope inside another one?

Tags: linq-to-sql, sql-server-ce, transactionscope

Here's a very simple example using SQL Server CE 3.5 SP1 where I attempt to use a new transaction inside an existing one.

```
using (var db = new MyDataContext(<connection string>))
using (var ts = new TransactionScope())
{
    db.Thing.InsertOnSubmit(new Thing());
    db.SubmitChanges();
    using (var ts2 = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
    {
        db.Thing.InsertOnSubmit(new Thing());
        db.SubmitChanges();   // exception here
        ts2.Complete();
    }
    [... do more stuff ...]
    ts.Complete();
}
```

This causes the error "The connection object can not be enlisted in transaction scope." on the second call to "db.SubmitChanges()"

[This article](http://documentation.genom-e.com/Genome/Default.aspx/GenomeDoc/99.TechTalk.Genome.RefGuide.chm%5Caref_Support.SqlCE.html) states that SQL CE does not support two connections inside one transaction, but I only have one here (unless SubmitChanges() creates another one).

The idea above is that if the sub-transaction commits then it stays committed even if the outer transaction fails. To the best of my understanding, this is [the intended use of RequiresNew](http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/jimjohn/archive/2005/06/18/11451.aspx).

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa275653%28SQL.80%29.aspx) claims that SQL CE supports nested transactions as such, hence my thinking that the above should be possible. Is it? If so, how do I modify the code to make this work?

*Edit*: While [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172400.aspx) contradicts the other MSDN article and says nested transactions are not supported. Perhaps that is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, you cannot use nested transactions.  Run this code on your SQL CE database and you will see the error message.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
SELECT 'GOT 1';
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
SELECT 'GOT 2';
```

Major Error 0x80004005, Minor Error 27994
Microsoft SQL Server Compact does not support nested transactions.

Answer (score 3):

In your case, you should not use TransactionScope.

You will have to call DataContext.Transaction = DataContext.Connection.BeginTransaction and control your own transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution: http://fknet.wordpress.com/2011/02/25/entity-framework-problemsolution-of-default-connection-closing/