# Trying to a Simple Transaction with EF CTP5 & SqlServerCE4.0 == failed. Why?

Tags: .net, transactions, sql-server-ce, transactionscope, sql-server-ce-4

I've got some code which is throwing an exception when I use this against SqlServer CE 4.0 & within a TransactionScope. First, the code, then the error.

```
// Arrange.
// ... some stuff ...
// like .. order = get order with ID #1.

// Act.
using (new TransactionScope())
{
    order.Name = name; // Update a field.
    _orderRepository.Save(order);
    _unitOfWork.Commit(); // <-- this works 100% fine.

    // Assert.
    // Reload the order so we can see if the data persisted to the DB.
    var updatedOrder = _orderRepository
    .Find()
    .Where(x => x.OrderId == 1)
    .SingleOrDefault(); <-- // this throws the exception.

    Assert.IsNotNull(updatedOrder);
    Assert.AreEqual(name, order.Name);
}
```

The exception error is:-

> System.Data.EntityException: The
>   underlying provider failed on Open.
>   ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The connection object can not be
>   enlisted in transaction scope.

So the first save/commit works fine but when I try to retrieve the object again (to see if the data persisted in the transaction) that's when the error occurs.

Now i'm sure this is a *Single Transaction* and not a *Distributed Transaction* ... so I'm assuming this should just work?

Suggestions, kind folk?

Comment: SQLCE does not support TransactionScope. Use normal DB transactions.

Comment: BTW this was asked a few weeks ago, but I cannot find the question now.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554473/linq-to-sql-does-sql-server-compact-ce-support-a-requiresnew-transaction-scop

Answer (score 0):

I had to fight with it and here is the possible solution: http://fknet.wordpress.com/2011/02/25/entity-framework-problemsolution-of-default-connection-closing/